# Improve performance of drawRect:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am drawing cells from a grid with a NSTimer every 0.1 Seconds.
The size is about 96x64 => 6144 cells / images.
If i am drawing images instead of (e.g.) green rectangles it is 4 times slower !

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height));
    int cellSize = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    double xOffset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT;j++)
        {                
                NSNumber *currentCell = [self.state.board objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j];
                if (currentCell.intValue == 1)
                {
                   [image1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xOffset + (cellSize * i),cellSize * j )];
                }
                else if (currentCell.intValue == 0){
                   [image2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xOffset + (cellSize * i),cellSize * j )];
                }
        }
    }
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Any idea how to makes this faster if i want to draw png or jpg in each rectangle?
The images are already scaled to an appropriate size.

Comment: Are the images actually resized image files, or are they just scaled in memory?

Comment: They are scaled in memory only right now. I tried scaling the files which had no result at all (was amazed)! Change was from 64x64 pixels to 10x10 pixels...

Comment: There is a lot of ways how the code can be improved for performance, e.g. transforming the multiplications in `CGPointMake` to additions, making the `self.levelState.board` a C array and not `NSArray`. However, the bottleneck here is not checking the area for repainting and also the repaint every `0.1 secs` seems a bit strange. Only games need such repainting and that's why we have OpenGL...

Comment: Why not split the view into many smaller views and set the images as each view's layer content?

Comment: I am also suspecting that it might be a mistake to do all that partial drawing in (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect.. Maybe its more effective to render the image in some method and then call the whole image with (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect....

Comment: "making the self.levelState.board a C array and not NSArray" anyone got a link to an example ?

Comment: @Shamino the `NSArray` is not the bottleneck here. Could you please provide some more context about how you are forcing the view to repaint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- a) Don't redraw the images/rects that are outside the view's bounds.
- b) Don't redraw the images/rects that are outside the dirtyRect
- c) Don't redraw the images/rects that haven't changes since the
  previous update.
- d) Use a layer to prerender the images, so you don't need to render
  them at drawing time.

Comment: a) check b) check c) How do i keep the old graphic context/make sure that only new rectangles are added and the old ones stay as they are? d) Does this work like a buffer ? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: right now i believe c) and d) are only possible if solved together because i am drawing in the current graphic context.. anything else i tried resulted in empty/grey pockets inbetween....

Comment: UIImage *currentContext = [self drawCurrentContext];
    [currentContext drawInRect:self.bounds]; Tried that with no result at all... still greyish blobs in-between... after consideration i think that i am doing right but calling drawCurrentContext to late...

Comment: You CANNOT hold on to the graphic context between calls to drawRect; the old graphic context isn't going to be valid after you return.  But you can render your images into CALayers -- read the Layer section of the Quartz docs.  ALSO: does every rectangle change every time?  If not, remember the state of the rectangles and don't re-render unchanged rectangles.

Comment: CALayer work but they are very slow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348785/change-contents-of-96x64-sublayers-in-a-nsmutablearray

Comment: CALayer's are EXTREMELY fast.  You're compositing 6144 layers, though, and that might be slow. Think it through.  Consider a less naive design; for example, instead of having each object own a layer, share the same layer between objects and let each have its own unique rectangle in which it draws. Only draw when something changes.

Comment: I can see your point. Anyone know a link / example / tutorial ...?

Comment: All i get so far are two rectangles dancing over a grey screen... cant find the appropriate mechanisms to achieve Mark´s suggestion....

Comment: Do i have to write my own LayerObject and implement -(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx for this ?

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is exactly what Instruments is there for. Use it. Anyone here making a suggestion is guessing about what the bottleneck is.

That said, I'm going to guess at what the bottleneck is. You are drawing 6114 images using the CPU (confirm this by using the time profiler. Find your drawRect method, and check where the most time is spent. If it's drawInRect, then that's your problem)

If that's the case, how do we reduce its usage? An easy win would be to only redraw the images we need to draw. CALayers make this easy. Remove your drawRect method, add a sublayer to your view's layer for each image, and set the images as your layers' content properties. Instead of invalidating the view when an image needs to change, just switch the relevant layer's content property to the new image.

Another nice thing about CALayers is that they cache layer content on the GPU, meaning that the redraws that do happen will require less CPU time and won't block the rest of you app as much when they do happen.

If the overhead of that many layers is unacceptable (again, Instruments is your friend), check out CAReplicatorLayer. It's less flexible than having many CALayers, but allows a single image to be replicated many times with minimal overhead.

Comment: opened new thread for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315619/how-to-draw-to-context-without-losing-it/15322628#15322628

Answer (score 1):

I tried to improve your code from performance perspective. However, check my comment about bottlenecks, too.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //UIGraphicsPushContext(context); //not needed UIView does it anyway

    //use [UIView backgroundColor] instead of this
    //CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    //CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height));

    int cellSize = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    double xOffset = 0;

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellSize, cellSize);
    NSUinteger cellIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        cellFrame.origin.x = xOffset;

        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, cellIndex++) {                
            cellFrame.origin.y = 0;

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, cellFrame) {
                NSNumber *currentCell = [self.state.board objectAtIndex:cellIndex];

                if (currentCell.intValue == 1) {
                    [image1 drawInRect:cellFrame];
                }
                else if (currentCell.intValue == 0) {
                    [image2 drawInRect:cellFrame];
                }
            }

            cellFrame.origin.y += cellSize;
        }

        cellFrame.origin.x += cellSize;
    }

    //UIGraphicsPopContext(context); //not needed UIView does it anyway
}
```

Comment: After implementing the above code there was a speedup about 10-20 frames per minute (not seconds).... i will use it in addition to the above, so thank you very much.. i cant give this answer a good rating because i am new if any one is able to please do so...

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGRectIntersects` to check if the rect of your image is inside the dirtyRect to check if you need to draw it.