# How to draw to context without losing it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am drawing `UIImage`s to/from a grid. I am currently only drawing the changes... and only the changes... but the old images are supposed to stay where they are... however right now they vanish after the next call of `drawRect:(CGRect)rect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    int cellSize = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    double xOffset = 0;

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellSize, cellSize);
    NSUInteger cellIndex = 0;
    cellFrame.origin.x = xOffset;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {        
        cellFrame.origin.y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, cellIndex++)
        {
            if([[self.state.boardChanges objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j] intValue]==1){
                if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, cellFrame))                {
                    NSNumber *currentCell = [self.state.board objectAtIndex:cellIndex];

                    if (currentCell.intValue == 1)
                    {
                        [image1 drawInRect:cellFrame];
                    }
                    else if (currentCell.intValue == 0)
                    {
                        [image2 drawInRect:cellFrame];
                    }
                }
            }
            cellFrame.origin.y += cellSize;
        }
        cellFrame.origin.x += cellSize;
    }   
}
```

I tried mixtures of the following without any results:

```
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    //CGContextAddRect(context, originalRect);
    CGContextClip(context);    
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution-> Just take a screenshot and draw it with drawRect as a background.

```
-(void)createContent{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    CGImageRef screenshotRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    _backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:screenshotRef];
    CGImageRelease(screenshotRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{   
    [_backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

######EDIT

Found a much more sophisticated way to do the above :
http://www.cimgf.com/2009/02/03/record-your-core-animation-animation/

#### EDIT

Another solution would be to use CALayers and only update those parts that change...

####EDIT

OR:

self.layer.contents = (id) [_previousContent CGImage];

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa/UIKit may discard the previously-drawn content of views whenever it likes. When your view is asked to draw, it must draw everything within the provided `rect`. You can't just decide to not draw some stuff. (Well, you can do whatever you like, but you get the results that you're seeing.)