# Change .contents of sublayers in a NSMutablearray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a 96x 64 grid of sublayers once,so i can easily update their .contents...

```
- (void)createLayer{
    CALayer *currentLayer = self.layer;

    _layerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:WIDTH*HEIGHT];
    int cellSize = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    double xOffset = 0;

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellSize, cellSize);
    NSUInteger cellIndex = 0;
    cellFrame.origin.x = xOffset;

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {
        cellFrame.origin.y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, cellIndex++)
        {                
            if([[self.levelState.boardChanges objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j] intValue]==1){
                {
                    NSNumber *currentCell = [self.levelState.board objectAtIndex:cellIndex];
                    CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
                    sublayer.frame = cellFrame;
                    if (currentCell.intValue == 1)
                    {
                        sublayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"].CGImage;
                    }
                    else if (currentCell.intValue == 0)
                    {
                        sublayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"].CGImage;
                    }
                    [currentLayer addSublayer:sublayer];
                    [_layerArray addObject:sublayer];
                }
            }
            cellFrame.origin.y += cellSize;
        }
        cellFrame.origin.x += cellSize;
    }
}
```

However i fail at exactly that.. what i tried is something like that...

```
[[_layerArray objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j ].contents ] = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"].CGImage;
```

How do i change their .contents ? Should i use NSArray instead ?

Thank you !

Comment: maybe something like that :? id subl = [_layerArray objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j ];
                        [subl.contents addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grass.png"]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[_layerArray objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j ] setContents:(id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"].CGImage];
```

But its very slow...

### final edit

the approach posted as topic above was much to slow... my final approach is the following:

UIViewController
has UIView
has CALayers as sublayers

Sublayers are:
1. The background at zindex 0
2. The frontImages which are blended images of sorts at higher zindexes....

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it looks as though it would work

```
[sublayer.contents addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
```

Comment: [[_layerArray objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j ].contents addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]]; throws a : " Property 'contents' not found on object of type 'id'"