# Mechanism to assign UIImages their own Rect inside a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have one or more CALayers which represent/fill the whole screen.
I want to fill those CALayers from a grid structure, using a lot of small Rects with images.

What i tried was assigning each Rect its own CALayer and an UIImage.
With over 6000 CALayers the result was very slow. Now i am looking for a way not to use that much CALayer. Maybe only the top level ones.

So ist there a mechanism to assign UIImages their own Rect inside a CALayer ?

Slow / bad code Example:

```
- (void)createLayer{
    CALayer *currentLayer = self.layer;

    _layerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:WIDTH*HEIGHT];
    int cellSize = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    double xOffset = 0;

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellSize, cellSize);
    NSUInteger cellIndex = 0;
    cellFrame.origin.x = xOffset;

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {
        cellFrame.origin.y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, cellIndex++)
        {                
            if([[self.levelState.boardChanges objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j] intValue]==1){
                {
                    NSNumber *currentCell = [self.levelState.board objectAtIndex:cellIndex];
                    CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
                    sublayer.frame = cellFrame;
                    if (currentCell.intValue == 1)
                    {
                        [[_layerArray objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j ] setContents:(id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"].CGImage];
                    }
                    else if (currentCell.intValue == 0)
                    {
                        [[_layerArray objectAtIndex:(i*HEIGHT)+j ] setContents:(id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"].CGImage];
                    }
                    [currentLayer addSublayer:sublayer];
                    [_layerArray addObject:sublayer];
                }
            }
            cellFrame.origin.y += cellSize;
        }
        cellFrame.origin.x += cellSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a very different approach.

subclass a uiview and use it as your background

in your uiview subclass, override

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

inside, you can draw your uiimages within rectangles you define

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)]; //first square
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]drawInRect:CGRectMake(10,0,10,10)]; // and another right beside it
```

you can study core graphics more to get a better idea

Comment: This works very nicely. However there is a speed issue CPU vs GPU. I was looking to speed exactly that up by using CALayers and GPU. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312792/improve-performance-of-drawrect

Comment: do you have to redraw all the cells? If you redraw only some of the cells(those that are changed) you could get significantly better speed